# Async job executed twice after optimisticLockException

Tags: java, activiti

we observed some strange situation during processing. We are using your engine in multi-clustered environment connected to one db. Our process definition contains serviceTask given below:

```
<serviceTask id="ms" name="ms" activiti:async="true" activiti:delegateExpression="${msDelegate}">
  <extensionElements> <activiti:failedJobRetryTimeCycle>R3/PT60M</activiti:failedJobRetryTimeCycle> </extensionElements>
</serviceTask>
```

Task is preceded by timerEvent waiting for start of the new month. In this month we spotted several situations like below (these are logs from one of application nodes - situation took place on one machine):

```
INFO [2016-06-01 00:11:20.949] [,o.a.c.s.S.S.Service           ,provideAsyncJobExecutor-7,,,,1] Outbound Message
INFO [2016-06-01 00:11:37.860] [,o.a.c.s.S.S.Service           ,provideAsyncJobExecutor-7,,,,1 Inbound Message
WARN [2016-06-01 00:11:37.947] [,.e.LoggingExecuteAsyncRunnable,provideAsyncJobExecutor-7,,,,1] Optimistic locking exception during job execution: 836c28ab-6fc6-11e6-80e5-005056aa1dfc
INFO [2016-06-01 00:11:59.582] [,o.a.c.s.S.S.Service           ,provideAsyncJobExecutor-7,,,,1] Outbound Message
INFO [2016-06-01 00:11:59.824] [,o.a.c.s.S.S.Service           ,provideAsyncJobExecutor-7,,,,1] Inbound Message
ERROR [2016-06-01 00:11:59.844] [,.e.LoggingExecuteAsyncRunnable,provideAsyncJobExecutor-7,,,,1] Job 836c28ab-6fc6-11e6-80e5-005056aa1dfc failed
```

Description of steps:

1 First Outbound Message / Inbound Message -> WS call ended with success.

2 Optimistic locking exception during job execution: 836c28ab-6fc6-11e6-80e5-005056aa1dfc

3 Outbound Message / Inbound Message -> same as #1, but ended with fail (because it has already been done)

My first concern - what could cause ActivitiOptimisticLockingException after first WS call? I couldn't find any logs showing, that this job was handled by another node in the same time.
And the second - what could cause second WS call in such short period of time, executed by the same thread? Do you have any suggestions, what could go wrong or where can we look for potential problems?

Activiti version: 5.19.0.2

Comment: An optimistic locking exception happens when two (or more) different threads (on the same machine or different machines) try to change data of the same execution/variable/etc. Could it be there is another part of the process instance running at the very same moment? Do you happen to have a stacktrace of the optimistic locking exception, it should tell you for which entity the exception was thrown.

For the second point: I'm guessing that's some default wait time/retry, although you got the failedJobRetryTimeCycle set. If you can add a (simplified) process def, that would help.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post you a stack trace, because it's only warn message and it haven't been logged.

From my analysis the second run of the same job was caused by waiting async-continue job in DB. The WS that is called by job was working very slow and that might cause our problem. But what is strange for my is the fact that we are working with thread pool configured as follows: max: 50 min: 10 that are working with 20 DB connections in pool. Do you think that this is correct or we should tune something in this? It's very strange, that job was stuck for about 5 minutes.

Comment: What do you mean with 'very slow'. By default, if a job takes more than 5 minutes, it is deemed to have failed/crashed, and the job can be picked up again by job executors. If it was more than 5 mins, than the optimistic locking exception is expected in this case.

Comment: I mean that WS calls was taking something about 1 minute and there was a lot of traffic there.

Answer (score 0):

Put in application.properties,For production i will not prefer it .

> camunda.bpm.job-execution.enabled=false